# Meromorphic function at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

I'm studing about meremorphic functions in complex analysis and I'm trying to understand the proofe of being a mereomorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ means the function is rational. I also read what went on [a question on meromorphic function at $\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323154/1003587) but what I don't understand is what happens if infinity is one of the poles. In that case, we can't take $q(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j), z_j$ are the poles, as they did in the proofe in the link above, since $z_j=\infty$. How is that setteled?

Comment: I think they meant using a polynomial to cancel the poles on $\Bbb{C}$ not the possible one at $\infty$

Comment: So my question is what do we do if one of the poles is at $\infty$?

Comment: What I said, you multiply with a polynomial to obtain an entire function meromorphic at $\infty$ which must be a polynomial.